# Renaming document gives file not found on uploaded documents

Tags: 2013, document-library, event-receivers

Im trying to do a seamingly simple task in SP 2013.

when the user either Creates a new doc (Ribbon>Files>New Document) or Uploads a File i
want them renamed to for example [original_filename]_[datetime].[ext]

I have added a feature receiver (ItemAdded-synchronous) and the core of this is(from [this QA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5c3dcc5d-3113-463d-8835-2a050b2471a6/change-file-name-in-event-handler-itemadding)) :

```
file.MoveTo(pathBeforeFileName + "/"+newFileName);
file.Update();
```

When I create new document it works as expected, but when I **upload** a doc, I get a file not found error right before the properties dialog pops up (or instead of it). The file is renamed correctly when I Close the error dialog.

*Am I missing a ways to inform SP that I have renamed the file, its obviously looking for to old filename?*

*If this is impossible to do, is there any way to distinguish "New Doc" from "Upload Doc"?*

**More details:**
I have updated item2[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef], but no difference.
I have changed back to asynchronous event receiver then I will get past the first error message and get to the properties-dialog, but then I get Another error message at the bottom of that saying *"The file [new filename] has been modified by [me] on [datetime]"*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?
I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Mikkel. No we went for a different approach instead, so the users didnt upload documents, instead they were generated from forms (for other reasons, but we got rid of this problem as well)

Comment: Ok. crap... But thanks for your answer. For others: Think I have narrowed the problem down to this: File.moveto() is a async operation. And the list is reloaded before the file is moved and expexting the file to be in the new place. Or the opposite.